# How do I know if two vectors are near parallel

Tags: vector, orthogonal

I am having some trouble finding parallel vectors because of floating point precision. How can I determine if the vectors are parallel with some tolerance?

I also need a check for orthogonality with tolerance.

Comment: Which Programming language do you use and how do you code your vectors in that language

Comment: I am guessing I just need to round the components to the desired precision

Comment: This is c#, and the vector is written with an x and a y.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For vectors `v1` and `v2` check if they are orthogonal by

```
abs(scalar_product(v1,v2)/(length(v1)*length(v2))) < epsilon
```

where `epsilon` is small enough. Analoguously you can use

```
scalar_product(v1,v2)/(length(v1)*length(v2)) > 1 - epsilon
```

for parallelity test and

```
scalar_product(v1,v2)/(length(v1)*length(v2)) < -1 + epsilon
```

for anti-parallelity.

Comment: That's right, and to check being parallel, you'd check to see if the left-hand-side expression was 1.0, rather than 0.0. That is you'd see if the difference from 1.0 was less than epsilon. In general you're comparing that expression with the cosine of the desired angle, since that expression is the cosine of the angle between the vectors.

Comment: To check for parallelity using scalar_product(v1,v2)/(length(v1)*length(v2)) > 1 - epsilon, should I take the abs of the left hand side?

Comment: @JoshC. It depends. If you take the absolute value also vectors pointing exactly opposite will be considered parallel. Then instead you can also write `abs(1-scalar_product/lengths)<epsilon`.

Comment: @Howard How can I know if two line segments are near collinear?

Comment: @Howard: Isn't taking a dot product enough for checking if they're orthogonal? Also for parallelity case, ||v1 x v2|| > 0 is enough. The divide is unnecessary in both cases.

Comment: @legends2k absolutely negative, what you need is cos(theta) or sin(theta) not norm(v)*norm(w)*cos(theta) or norm(v)*norm(w)*sin(theta) that's why we eliminate norm(v)*norm(w) by dividing, also since definition of parallelity is vectors being linearly dependent two vectors pointing in opposite directions are also considered parallel

Comment: @Pooria I think you don't understand the optimization here; say if two vectors are linearly dependant, what as the possible angles between them 0, π, 2π, etc. sin (nπ) = 0 : ∀ n ∈ ℤ, thus ‖v1 ⨯ v2‖ = 0 * ‖v1‖ * ‖v2‖ = 0, so there's no need to actually divide by ‖v1‖ * ‖v2‖ to find the actual sine value. A similar argument holds for orthogonality too.

Comment: @legends2k mathematically correct but when dealing with floating point computation though due to round-off errors incorrect

Comment: this is the method to be used for three.js - for parallel check `Math.abs(v1.dot(v2) / (v1.length() * v2.length())) > 1 - Number.EPSILON`

Answer (score 3):

If you have 3D vectors the answer is simple. Compute the cross product and if it is nearly zero, your vectors are nearly parallel: 
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParallelVectors.html

For 2d vectors you can convert them into 3D vectors just by adding a coordinate with zero
(1;2) => (1;2;0), (4; 5.6) => (4; 5.6; 0) and so on

Two vectors are orthogonal or perpendicular, if there dot product ist zero:
<strike>http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CrossProduct.html</strike>

-edit
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Perpendicular.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with 3D vectors, you can do this concisely using the toolbelt [vg](https://github.com/lace/vg). It's a light layer on top of numpy and it supports single values and stacked vectors.

```
import numpy as np
import vg

v1 = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
v2 = np.array([-2.0, -4.0, -6.0])

vg.almost_collinear(v1, v2)
# True
```

I created the library at my last startup, where it was motivated by uses like this: simple ideas which are verbose or opaque in NumPy.